# Delete line in SQL based on advanced filtering

Tags: sql, request

I have quite a big database I need to clean up for legal reasons. Though I'm a webdev, I'm fairly unexperienced when it comes to SQL queries.

The context is a CRM with the fields "contact", "company" and "source".

"source" has 4 possible values : source1, source2, source3, and sources4

"source1" should be gotten rid of for legal reasons and so the dupes that originally came from source1.

As a matter of fact, some companies are duplicates and marked with up to 3 sources as they were imported and reimported from older databases.

This is how it shows :

```
**name | company | source**
name1 |  company1 |  source1 *< delete row (rows with source1 must be deleted)* 
name1 |  company1 |  source2 *< delete row (company1 comes from source1)*
name1 |  company1 |  source3 *< delete row (company1 comes from source1)*
name2 |  company2 |  source1 *< delete row (rows with source1 must be deleted)*
name2 |  company2 |  source2 *< delete row (company2 comes from source1)*
name3 |  company3 |  source2 *< keep row (company3 doesn't come from source1)*
name4 |  company4 |  source3 *< keep row*
name5 |  company5 |  source4 *< keep*
```

What I need to do is :

1- Get rid of the lines where a company has source2 and a dupe featuring source1.

2- once this is done, do the same with all contacts that have source2 and a dupe featuring source1

I really don't know what/if a SQL request could do that and what commands I should use.

Is it even possible ?

Thank you !

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: I'm sorry, I only put the tag that were suggested and added sql and request by myself. I wasn't aware I shouldn't have used the suggested tags. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a subquery in the WHERE clause, like this:

```
DELETE FROM mytable
  WHERE mytable.company IN (SELECT   mytable.company
                                FROM mytable
                               WHERE mytable.source = 'source1'
                            GROUP BY mytable.company)
```

Another alternative would be using [EXISTS](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php).

MySQL workaround (because it won't allow the table being altered to be used in the WHERE clause):

```
DELETE FROM mytable
  WHERE mytable.company IN (SELECT   mytbl.company
                                FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) as mytbl
                               WHERE mytbl.source = 'source1'
                            GROUP BY mytbl.company)
```

Comment: Thank you DouglasCamargo. That's indeed very helpful as I'm starting to grasp the concept.

Comment: Actually @DouglasCamargo, I get an error message : MySQL answered: Documentation
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'mytable' for update in FROM clause (obviously, I replaced the values in your example with my own)

Comment: This happens because MySQL won't let you use the same table you're modifying in the subselect... The workaround would be changing the subselect to: IN (SELECT   mytable.company
                                FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) ...

Comment: Well... I guess I understand it but I'm not sure that's what I want. I may rephrase my query by saying: if source1 exists for a company and source2 exit in the duplicate of this company, then delete both row featuring this company.

Comment: But that's what the query does, first it checks all the companies that have source1 (subquery) and then deletes all the rows that contain those companies... basically, that's what you asked. If you want a different result, try editing your question

Comment: Where does the request make sure that all dupes that now exist in source2, source3 and source4 are gotten rid of ? I don't get this bit.